# Remote Desktop password field doesn't have focus

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2016

I am on a corporate network, on a Windows Server 2016 Standard box.

When I try to open Remote Desktop (mstsc.exe) from this box to go to any other one (mostly Windows Server 2012), I normally expect to start typing my password right away as that is the field that previously would have focus. But it doesn't have focus, and no amount of tabbing will give it focus.

Has anyone else experienced this issue? Is there a fix?

Comment: Strangely, Feature update to Windows 10 Enterprise, version 1703 fixed the issue for me.

Comment: @Nixphoe why strangely? You should submit that as an answer. Unfortunately I can't receive that update as I'm on Windows Server instead of 10 but still... It does seem to have fixed it for our Windows 10 users here

Comment: @Nacht Done and thanks for clarifying.... Try updating your servers with the latest Windows Updates if you have not already or at least start with the one machine and one of the clients affected by the problem. You can delete your own comments by pressing the "X" on each of your comments. Tag me back when you see this and I will remove this comment of mine too. Good job!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same issue. I tried the following to resolve it

```
Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth
Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
SFC /scannnow
```

Each said there were no issues. On my Windows 10 machine I installed [Feature update to Windows 10 Enterprise, version 1703](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/whats-new/whats-new-windows-10-version-1703) which fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is very much a workaround, but would this work for you?

Skrommel's LabelControl program on DonationCoder overlays a number on window controls, enabling you to give it focus with Ctrl-[Number].

Link: http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Skrommel/index.html#LabelControl

As a more seamless workaround, it should be pretty easy to write an AutoHotKey script that automatically gives a certain text field focus.