# Starting recent remote desktop entry does not put focus in the password field

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, focus

When I start a remote desktop session through the "recent items" list in the Windows 10 task bar:

[image: screenshot 1]

I get the credentials window as expected:

[image: screenshot 2]

However, when I start typing my password, nothing happens. It appears that the focus is still in the Windows 10 task bar:

[image: screenshot 3]

In particular, the focus appears to still be *on the item in the "recent" list*, because as soon as I hit the space bar (yes, my password on that machine contains a space), another instance of the credentials window (second screenshot in this question) opens.

I can only type my password after explicitly clicking into the password field, which is *super annoying* (especially since it worked before). It *might* have started happening after the upgrade to Windows 10 v2004, but I'm not sure.

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: Note: I found [this related question](https://superuser.com/q/1264343/14517) (Remote Desktop password field doesn't have focus) but that's about an issue with an earlier version of Windows 10/Server 2016.

Comment: Have you tried the solutions found at that thread? Or can't you save your credentials?

Comment: @Wasif_Hasan: Well, updating to v1703 won't make much sense on a v2004 machine :-), and I'm pretty sure that LabelControl can only work if the application itself has focus. Since I have administrative access on the target machines, I'd like to avoid saving credentials for security reasons.

Comment: Nope, run the `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth` and `sfc /scannow` scans.

Comment: @Wasif_Hasan: Done, nothing found. Problem still persists.

Comment: I get this too, it's incredibly annoying. I feel like one day I'm going to blat my password into team chat, although if you're right about the focus then that's a small relief to know that I won't actually.

Comment: Yep I get this too, super frustrating! I've submitted it as feedback to MS via feedback hub. We might get a fix in a few years time!